# RecyclerView con Fechas

Tags: android, date, recyclerview, método

Quiero realizar un filtro en un recyclerView Con Fechas. Para ello realizo una consulta sobre la db SQLite, la vuelco en un cursor. He creado un método al cual se le pasan dos variables tipo date `di=fechaInicio` y `df=FechaFin`. Mi problema es que no sé como debo comparar las fecha y sobre todo darles formato para poder filtrar. Éste en mi código del método, me aparece error en el momento de darle formato a la fecha

```
private void consultarListaDietas(Date di, Date df) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getReadableDatabase();
    Dieta dieta = null;
    Date date = new Date();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Utilidades.TABLA_DIETAS, null);
    if (di == null && df == null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            dieta = new Dieta();
            dieta.setId_Dieta(cursor.getInt(0));
            dieta.setNoches(cursor.getInt(1));
            dieta.setKm(cursor.getDouble(2));
            String fecha = cursor.getString(3);
            DateFormat iso8601Format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            try {
                date = iso8601Format.parse(fecha);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Parsing ISO8601 datetime failed", e);
            }
            dieta.setFecha(date);
            dieta.setId_Usuario_FK(cursor.getInt(4));
            dieta.setId_Proyecto_FK(cursor.getInt(5));

        }

    } else {
        String fechaFin = df.toString();
        String fechaInicio = di.toString();
        cursor = null;
        String[] args = new String[]{fechaInicio, fechaFin};
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Utilidades.TABLA_DIETAS + " WHERE Fecha BETWEEN ? AND ?", args);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            dieta = new Dieta();
            dieta.setId_Dieta(cursor.getInt(0));
            dieta.setNoches(cursor.getInt(1));
            dieta.setKm(cursor.getDouble(2));
            String fecha = cursor.getString(3);
            DateFormat iso8601Format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            try {
                date = iso8601Format.parse(fecha);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Parsing ISO8601 datetime failed", e);
            }
            dieta.setFecha(date);
            dieta.setId_Usuario_FK(cursor.getInt(4));
            dieta.setId_Proyecto_FK(cursor.getInt(5));

        }
    }
}
```

Os paso el código de selección de fechas:

```
@Override

    public void onClick(View v) {

        //método para mostrar fecha cuando pinche el botón
        if (v==btinicio) {
            dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            ano = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    txtinicio.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
                }
            }, ano,mes,dia);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
        if (v == btfin) {
            dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            ano = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    txtfin.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
                }
            }, ano,mes,dia);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: lo ideal sería guardar las fechas como long para comparar

Comment: como dice @armen guarda el timestamp en Long con el UnixTime